# Exception while running StreamingContext.start()

Tags: pyspark, apache-kafka

Exception while running python code in Windows 10. I am using Apache Kafka and PySpark.

Python code snippet to read data from Kafka

```
ssc=StreamingContext(sc,60)
zkQuorum, topic = sys.argv[1:]       
kvs=KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, "spark-streaming-consumer", {topic: 1})
lines = kvs.map(lambda x: [x[0],x[1]])
lines.pprint()
lines.foreachRDD(SaveRecord)
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Exception while running the code

```
Exception in thread "streaming-start" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/internal/Logging$class
            at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver.<init>(KafkaInputDStream.scala:69)
            at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaInputDStream.getReceiver(KafkaInputDStream.scala:60)
            at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker.$anonfun$launchReceivers$1(ReceiverTracker.scala:441)
            at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:237)
            at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:36)
            at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
            at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:198)
            at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:237)
            at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:230)
            at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:198)
            at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker.launchReceivers(ReceiverTracker.scala:440)
            at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker.start(ReceiverTracker.scala:160)
            at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler.start(JobScheduler.scala:102)
            at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.$anonfun$start$1(StreamingContext.scala:583)
            at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
            at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$$anon$1.run(ThreadUtils.scala:145)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
            ... 16 more
```

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem? Currently, I am facing exactly the same error. Let me know if you've solved it as I am still figuring it out how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to incompatible version of Scala with Spark. Make sure your Scala Version in Project configuration matches with the Version your Spark Version supports.
Spark requires Scala 2.12; support for Scala 2.11 was removed in Spark 3.0.0

It is also possible that the third party jar (like dstream-twitter for twitter streaming application or your Kafka streaming jar) is built for unsupported version of Scala in your application.

For me dstream-twitter_2.11-2.3.0-SNAPSHOT For Instance didn't work with Spark 3.0, It gave Exception in thread "streaming-start" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/internal/Logging$class). But when I updated the dtream-twitter jar with scala 2.12 version it solved the issue.

Make sure you get all the Scala Versions correct.